# SwiftUI zIndex not updating correctly inside ForEach

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui, xcode11

This issue occurs in Xcode 11 GM.

When a view is tapped the colour will change to blue and the zIndex should be updated to move it to the front.

With the top example this works fine and you will never see a green view overlap a blue view. In the bottom example (using the ForEach) it doesn't redraw correctly and the blue view stays behind the green.

Although strangely if you have the bottom example in a bad state and then touch any of the views in top then the bottom will suddenly correct itself.

Any ideas or solution?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            // First example, working
            TestView().position(x: 100, y: 100)
            TestView().position(x: 200, y: 200)

            // Second example, not working
            ForEach(1..<3) { i in
                TestView().position(x: 100*CGFloat(i), y: 300 + 100*CGFloat(i))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {

    @State var isTapped = false

    var body: some View {

        return Text("Test Test Test")
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .background(isTapped ? Color.blue : Color.green)
            .zIndex(isTapped ? 100 : 0)
            .gesture(
                TapGesture()
                    .onEnded {
                        self.isTapped.toggle()
                }
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: The zIndex's in the ForEach are being updated but it seems that that change is being blocked by the ForEach. When the first 2 are updated the Stack sees the change immediately and redraws the whole view. You could probably work around it by passing a binding from ContentView that causes an update.

Comment: I have the same problem. @MichaelSalmon what do you mean exactly?

Comment: He's saying that the parent view may not notice that a zindex has changed, and therefore doesn't reflect it. The parent view only triggers a redraw when it sees a change and a zIndex, may be too small a change for the parent view to "notice". To test this theory, you could use a binding to force a redraw of the parent view. There is a similar issue with Pickers.